# Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 tflearn error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I am using a DNN provided by `tflearn` to learn from some data. My `data` variable has a shape of `(6605, 32)` and my `labels` data has a shape of `(6605,)` which I reshape in the code below to `(6605, 1)`...

```
# Target label used for training
labels = np.array(data[label], dtype=np.float32)

# Reshape target label from (6605,) to (6605, 1)
labels = tf.reshape(labels, shape=[-1, 1])

# Data for training minus the target label.
data = np.array(data.drop(label, axis=1), dtype=np.float32)

# DNN
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 32])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model.
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```

This gives me a couple of errors, the first is...

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [6605,1], [1,16], [1,16], [1].

...and the second is...

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [6605,1], [1,16], [1,16], [1].

I  have no idea what `rank 1` and `rank 2` are, so I do not have an idea as to how to fix this issue.

Comment: Try dropping the reshaping of `labels`; does the error persist? It yes pls provide a sample of your data (also, any link where this model is provided, as you say, will be useful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Tensorflow, rank is the number of dimensions of a tensor (not similar to the matrix rank). As an example, following tensor has a rank of 2.

```
t1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
print(t1.shape) # prints (3, 3)
```

Moreover, following tensor has a rank of 3.

```
t2 = np.array([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
print(t2.shape) # prints (2, 2, 3)
```

Since **tflearn** is build on top of Tensorflow, inputs should not be tensors. I have modified your code as follows and commented where necessary.

```
# Target label used for training
labels = np.array(data[label], dtype=np.float32)

# Reshape target label from (6605,) to (6605, 1)
labels =np.reshape(labels,(-1,1)) #makesure the labels has the shape of (?,1)

# Data for training minus the target label.
data = np.array(data.drop(label, axis=1), dtype=np.float32)
data = np.reshape(data,(-1,32)) #makesure the data has the shape of (?,32)

# DNN
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 32])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model.
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```

Hope this helps.