# TF Hub Universal Sentence Encoder Fine-tuning for sentence similarity

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

I'm working on fine-tuning the USE v4 model from tf hub.
The dataset used is a sentence pair with target label [0,1].

Following is my code,

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4', 
                        input_shape=[2,], 
                        dtype=tf.string, 
                        trainable=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

resulting in error,

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for '{{node text_preprocessor/tokenize/StringSplit/StringSplit}} = StringSplit[skip_empty=true](text_preprocessor/StaticRegexReplace_1, text_preprocessor/tokenize/StringSplit/Const)' with input shapes: [?,2], [].
```

It would be great if someone can help me understand where I have gone wrong.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233537/shape-must-be-rank-1-but-is-rank-2-tflearn-error

Comment: you have to put `input_shape=[]`

Comment: But the training data is of rank 2, anyways when I run ```model.fit()``` with input_shape=[] for the training data, I get following error, ```ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for '{{node text_preprocessor/tokenize/StringSplit/StringSplit}} = StringSplit[skip_empty=true](text_preprocessor/StaticRegexReplace_1, text_preprocessor/tokenize/StringSplit/Const)' with input shapes: [?,2], [].```

Answer (score 1):

As @qmeeus mentioned, input_shape need to be [], or you can skip specify the input_shape all together. So something like the following:

```
use_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/4"


feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(use_url, input_shape=[], trainable=True)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_extractor_layer,
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

This [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/409) might be helpful.

In order to pass in a pair of sentences, you can reuse the feature_extractor_layer in a Siamese network.